# How to display value from asyncio in web browser page using WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm new to asyncio and aiohttp as well as WebSockets. Basically, I need to generate a random string, change it every second and display its value on the web page without refreshing.

I wrote the following code:
**app.py**

```
import asyncio
import random
import string

from aiohttp import web


async def index(request):
    return web.Response(text=periodic())

@asyncio.coroutine
def periodic():
    while True:
        print(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10)))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

def stop():
    task.cancel()

task = asyncio.Task(periodic())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    pass
```

But it only displays random string value in the console.

**main.py**

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import setup_routes


app = web.Application()
setup_routes(app)
web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

**routes.py**

```
from app import index


def setup_routes(app):
    app.router.add_get('/', index)
```

I know that I need to use WebSockets for this task but can't understand from the tutorials how to implement and connect all the components. Will be glad if somebody can help me.

Comment: If you can accept a "pull" solution instead of a "push", you do not necessarily need to use a websocket. Instead you can update your webpage with "standard" AJAX. In all cases you must write some javascript code to handle the data reception at the webpage end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolved it on the client side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var conn = null;
      function log(msg) {
        var control = $('#log');
        control.html('');
        control.html(msg);
        control.scrollTop(control.scrollTop() + 1000);
      }
      function connect() {
        disconnect();
        var wsUri = (window.location.protocol=='https:'&&'wss://'||'ws://')+window.location.host;
        conn = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        log('Connecting...');
        conn.onopen = function() {
          log('Connected.');
          console.log(conn);
        };
        conn.onmessage = function(e) {
          log('Received: ' + e.data);
        };
        conn.onclose = function() {
          log('Disconnected.');
          conn = null;
        };
      }
      function disconnect() {
        if (conn != null) {
          log('Disconnecting...');
          conn.close();
          conn = null;
        }
      }

      $('#connect').click(function() {
        if (conn == null) {
          connect();
        } else {
          disconnect();
        }
        return false;
      });
      function repeat(){
          var text = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
          log(text);
          conn.send(text);
          setTimeout(repeat, 1000);
      };
      $('#start').click(function() {
        repeat();
        $('#text').val('').focus();
        return false;
      });
      $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          $('#send').click();
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <button id="connect">Connect</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="start">start</button>
</div>
<div id="log"
     style="width:20em;height:15em;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```